# How to Display Select Tag using 'change' jquery 2.1.4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display select box when user  input some values in the textbox , I tried using onchange property of jquery but its not working.

Below is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#total_enter").change(function() {
    $(".gst_sel_wrap").css("display", "block");
  });
})
```

```css
.gst_sel_wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_box">
  <input type="text" name="total_enter" id="total_enter">
  <select class="gst_sel_wrap">
    <option>GST SLABS</option>
    <option value="">0%</option>
    <option value="">5%</option>
    <option value="">12%</option>
    <option value="">18%</option>
    <option value="">28%</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean you want to show all options when someone enters text?

Comment: what do you mean it's not working? it seems to work here, the select takes correctly the `block` display. What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: you need to leave the input text, Onchange apply when you end typing and not when typing

Comment: it is just simply `$(".gst_sel_wrap").show();` not `$(".gst_sel_wrap").css("display", "block");`

Comment: @juntapao it does the same thing. I think it's rather a good pratice to use `css` when you are using css rules. More understandable to use `show` when you actually use `hide` imo

Comment: @venkatesh Konatham , yup , well below code snippet worked fine for me,

Comment: @Kaddath `I think it's rather a good pratice to use css when you are using css rules` It's actually better to avoid `css()` where possible, as it ties the JS and CSS code together, which is a very bad idea. Always put styling in external stylesheets and use `addClass()` where possible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes i totally agree with you, i don't recommend equally `css()` or `show() / hide()` for the reason that they all add inline css. I was just talking about code readability when you actually use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you can use the `input` event, as it fires when a key is pressed and also when a value is copy/pasted in. You should also check the value of the element to ensure that it isn't empty, as the value can be deleted, when I would assume your select should be hidden again.

Finally, note that you can use `toggle()` to hide or show the select based on the given value, in a more succinct way. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#total_enter").on('input', function() {
    $(".gst_sel_wrap").toggle(this.value.trim() != '');
  });
})
```

```css
.gst_sel_wrap {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_box">
  <input type="text" name="total_enter" id="total_enter">
  <select class="gst_sel_wrap">
    <option>GST SLABS</option>
    <option value="">0%</option>
    <option value="">5%</option>
    <option value="">12%</option>
    <option value="">18%</option>
    <option value="">28%</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the jQuery `keydown` method: https://api.jquery.com/keydown/

I also added some code to hide the dropdown in the beginning, so the effect becomes obvious.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".gst_sel_wrap").hide();
  $("#total_enter").keydown(function(){
    $(".gst_sel_wrap").show();
  }); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_box">
  <input type="text" name="total_enter" id="total_enter">
   <select class="gst_sel_wrap">
    <option>GST SLABS</option>
    <option value="">0%</option>
    <option value="">5%</option>
    <option value="">12%</option>
    <option value="">18%</option>
    <option value="">28%</option>
  </select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) or [`keydown`](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/) or both as I do here:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#total_enter").on("keyup keydown",function() {
    $(".gst_sel_wrap").css("display", "block");
  });
})
```

```css
.gst_sel_wrap {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap_box">
  <input type="text" name="total_enter" id="total_enter">
  <select class="gst_sel_wrap">
                          <option>GST SLABS</option>
                          <option value="">0%</option>
                          <option value="">5%</option>
                          <option value="">12%</option>
                          <option value="">18%</option>
                          <option value="">28%</option>
                    </select>
</div>
```